# Insert Hyperlink to an IP Address

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel, google-chrome, firefox, dns

I can open a browser *(Chrome or Firefox or Internet Explorer)* and enter an IP address in the Address bar, say:

```
134.170.185.46
```

and the browser will open the website *(Microsoft.com)* directly - bypassing any need to resolve the DNS.

I am trying to insert a hyperlink in an Excel worksheet cell to do the same thing.  I have tried the following:

```
=HYPERLINK("134.170.185.46","microsoft")
=HYPERLINK("www.134.170.185.46","microsoft")
=HYPERLINK("http://www.134.170.185.46","microsoft")
```

But none of them work.

[image]

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the following?:

`=HYPERLINK("http://134.170.185.46","microsoft")`